# What is the symbol for blockchain eos in googlefinance in EUR and GBP

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

My google sheet returns Na when I write

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("EOSEUR")

# or

=GOOGLEFINANCE("EOSGBP")
```

However, when I introduce

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BTCEUR")

# or 

=GOOGLEFINANCE("EOS")
```

I got the right output.

Where can I find a list of symbols for all blockchains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try alternative:

```
=INDEX(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EOS-EUR/"; 
 "//div[@data-reactid='32']")); 2; 1)
```

---

```
=INDEX(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EOS-GBP/"; 
 "//div[@data-reactid='32']")); 2; 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have got now this data 1975995 and this for EOS-GBP -576292. This makes not sense to me

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rgQ3vgV-VFu9qPAcVAKnMl1KFCtc8iaqr1GFySsFXUw/edit#gid=0